# Continuous functions with specified area under them in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that there is only one continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying 
$$\int_0^1 f(x)(1-f(x))\,dx=1/4.$$ 
I am able to see that the constant function $f(x)=1/2$ satisfies the hypotheses but I just can’t prove uniqueness. Help please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$0\leq \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{2}-f(x)\right)^2\,dx=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{4}-f(x)+f(x)^2\right)\,dx=\frac{1}{4}-\int_0^1 f(x)(1-f(x))\,dx.$$

Comment: Nice simple answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

For every real number $u$, $$u(1-u)\le {1\over 4}$$so that $$f(x)[1-f(x)]\le {1\over 4}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=1/2$ qualifies.

Assume there is another continuos function $g(x)$

Set $g(x):=1/2+h(x)$;

$\int_{0}^{1}((1/2)+h(x))(1/2-h(x))dx=$

$\int_{0}^{1}((1/4)-h^2(x))dx=$

$(1/4)-\int_{0}^{1}h^2(x)dx;$

$h(x)$ continuous implies $h(x) \equiv 0$.